# Summing up the table text field values in dynamic html table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am trying to sum up the total of same category in dynamic table.

Please refer my code in Jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/Z7fG7/129/

Dynamic table category to be summed up and should set to the below table Please help me am stucked

```
<table id="test">
<tr>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="Mango" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="Apple" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="MuskMelon" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add" id="addCategory" onclick="AddCategory()" />

<h2>Result Table</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Total Mango</td>
    <td><input type="text"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Total Apple</td>
    <td><input type="text"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Total MuskMelon</td>
    <td><input type="text"  /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
 var i = 1;

 $(document).on('click', 'button.addCategory', function () {

     var tableRow = "<tr><td><select><option>Mango</option><option>Appple</option><option>MuskMelon</option></select></td><td><input type=text/></td></tr>";
    $('#test').append(tableRow);

     return false;
 });

 $(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
     alert("aa");
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: Please help me on this

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want to sum up the total of textfield values on category wise.
I have created http://jsfiddle.net/Z7fG7/129/ Please refer

Comment: Then why have you commented the next fiddle?